# Count delimiter(s) of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

`$search = " I-love-stackoverflow ";`

I am trying to count the dash in my string `$search` , here is what I tried :

```
$count_dash = preg_match('/-/', $search);
```

and I keep getting **1** as my result.

`dd( count($count_dash));` // result = [image]

As you can see, the answer should be **2**.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: `echo substr_count($search, '-');` - PHP docs are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: you don't need a regex here. If you want, then use preg_match_all

Comment: @MarkBaker : How to detect the last `-` ? I want to grab whatever before the second " - " , which is `I-love`

Comment: If you always want to find what's before the __last__ `-`, then `echo substr($search, 0, strrpos($search, '-'));`

Comment: Opp, I got it. I use `strrpos` then follow by `substr` .... never mind.

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly - what I did. Thanks for your time. :D